# jQuery Validation Plugin: error class on all checkbox inputs in group

Tags: jquery, html, validation, checkbox

I'm using the jQuery Validation Plugin on a form and I'm having problems styling a checkbox group. The plugin adds a class (.error) to the invalid input which I'm using to change the colour of the input.

The problem is that when you validate on a group of checkboxes it only adds the class to the first checkbox in the group. I would like it to behave in the same way radio inputs do. When none are selected they all get the error class, then when one is selected they all get the valid class.

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/paulyabsley/pen/zFkbI/): reduced test case with a checkbox input group and radio input group.

Submitting the form in the demo you can see that only the first checkbox gets the error class but *all radio inputs* get it.

```
// Example html
<form action="#" id="form" method="post">
  <ul>  
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox1">
      <label for="checkbox1">Mike</lable>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox2">
      <label for="checkbox2">November</lable>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox3">
      <label for="checkbox3">Oscar</lable>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

// Validation Plugin Config
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      "checkbox[]": {
         required: true,
         minlength: 1
         },
       radio: "required",
     },

     validClass: "js-valid",
     errorLabelContainer: ".js-errors",
     errorElement: "li",

     messages: {
       "checkbox[]": "Please select at least one checkbox",
       radio: "Please choose from the Radio Group",
     },
   });
 });
```

I found [this suggestion](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-only-first-checkbox-is-highlighted-if-there-is-an-error) in the jQuery forums but when I tried doing that the error class seemed to be applied to all the checkboxes but selecting one didn't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been unable to add a class to each checkbox input so I've worked around it using the [highlight and unhighlight](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) options in the plugin.

```
// Validation Plugin Config
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      "checkbox[]": {
         required: true,
         minlength: 1
       },
    radio: "required",
  },

  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass); // add error class to elements/remove valid class
    $(element).closest('ul').addClass(errorClass); // add error class to ul element for checkbox groups and radio inputs
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass); // remove error class from elements/add valid class
    $(element).closest('ul').removeClass(errorClass); // remove error class from ul element for checkbox groups and radio inputs
  },

  errorLabelContainer: ".js-errors",
  errorElement: "li",

  messages: {
    "checkbox[]": "Please select at least one checkbox",
    radio: "Please choose from the Radio Group",
  },
 });
```

});

They add the error class to the parent ul which allows me to select and style the child inputs with css. Bit of a hack really but it gets the desired results

Comment: Sounds good to me - consider filing a bug on the project over at github, it may turn out this is something that needs fixing:  https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation